# How to check if a cell that contains text matches two other cells?

Tags: excel, if-statement, text, excel-formula, match

I'm matching the names of my students with their scores. Example:

```
     A           B          C        D         E     F      G
1   ADAM       10        ADAM      8.5      ADAM     9     OK
2   LUKE       10        LUKE        9      JOHN     9   FALSE
3   JOHN       9         JOHN        8      LUKE    10   FALSE
4   LUCY       8.5       LUCY        9      LUCY     8     OK
```

Columns A and B are the names and scores for Mathematics.
Columns C and D are the names and scores for English.
Columns E and F are the names and scores for History.

I need the formula to check if A1, C1, and E1 contain the same text and if so fill G1 with `OK`.
 If one of them is different, then the G1 should show `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF and AND function:

```
=IF(AND(B2=D2,D2=F2),"OK","FALSE")
```

In this case the three name is in B2, D2 and F2.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a slight variation:

```
=IF(AND(A1=C1,A1=E1),"OK")
```

in G1 and copied down to suit.